# How do you use Mosaico templates with Pretty Workflow Messages?

Tags: email, mosaico, system-workflow-messages

How do you use Mosaico templates with Pretty Workflow Messages?
Using latest Civi w/ Wordpress.

https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/prettyworkflowmessages/
Says it works with mosaico, but none of my mosaico templates appear as options on the admin page.

Answer (score 2):

For now - this is my workaround:

- Install [Mosaico Message Templates](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/mosaicomsgtpl)
- Go to Message Templates, since the edit option is disabled, copy the link to edit one of the other templates and edit the ID in the URL to another number (usually larger, mine was only 6 away), until you discover the template you want to edit.
- Do not make edits there, instead copy the message body, go back to message templates, create a new template and then paste the message body into the new template.
- add your tokens, make any changes you need, save and then you should be good to go!

There must be an easier way, but at-least this worked for me. When I just tried to do it using the template that mosaico message templates generates, i would get smarty errors.

Comment: I think easiest way would be to create new branding template after `Mosaico Message Templates` extension is enabled. You don't need to manually edit Message templates. All the configuration could be done in normal Mosaico interface. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I know I don't need to edit, but I can't create a new template based or duplicate a template based off the mosaico ones, the options are not there. Thats why I have to do the edit trick, I don't actually edit anything, I just copy content and paste into new template.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you.

Yes, currently Pretty workflow messages have dependency on `Mosaico Message Templates` if you are using Mosaico based branding template.

I have updated the [readme](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/prettyworkflowmessages/-/blob/master/README.md) to reflect the same.